# What could cause an UmbrellaException anonymous function on deployed GWT app?

Tags: javascript, caching, exception, gwt

I seem to be running into an odd problem. When using my GWT application in a local environment, everything works as it should. The problem comes in after I compile and deploy my application. When I go through my project workflow and click on a certain link to switch into a new panel, I get the following error (from my console in Chrome):

```
Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions
caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses (anonymous function)
```

This error is thrown by one of the cache file generated by GWT at compile time. But this never happens on the locally deployed program (deployed from Eclipse, "Run as Web Application"). Has anyone ever run into this issue or can provide any direction for a fix?

Thank you! :)

Comment: What's the full stack trace? UmbrellaExceptions include what error caused it, further down the stack.

Comment: There is no stack trace. The Chrome error console just shows that one exception and says "(anonymous function)"

When just deploying locally using Eclipse, this exception doesnt occur, so there is no trace.

Comment: put in a try catch and print the stack traces of the nested exceptions.

Comment: There is a generated try catch in the cache code. The cache is generated by GWT so we do not touch it. There also isnt any sort of correspondence with the Java, so theres no way to know where it originates from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem just now. Works locally, fails with the mentioned Javascript console error, nothing in server logs.

Turns out that client Java code (which is complied to Javascript) had try/catch block which worked when executed in Java, but failed silently when compiled to Javascript. I'm still not sure what was the exact nature of the problem, but try removing try/catch blocks.

(It seems that in my case, `table.getWidget()` call was failing and throwing exception.)

Comment: Best answer so far. We actually never got down to the root of the problem, but switched our panel transition workflow and that seemed to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i think interpretation of try catch is not the same than in Java... after gwt compilation, when you are in catch case, the execution failed. If you open firebug, you can see point of errors into JS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it worked in development mode. Then, after I compiled I would get an error. To fix, I had to get rid of:

```
try{
   //some code
} catch(NullPointerException ex){
   //more code
}
```

Instead I did:

```
if(variable != null){
   //some code
} else {
   //more code
}
```

After that it worked perfectly.